# Remove special character in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
REPLACE(ab.FirstName,', '')
```

How can i remove only this character  '  from a string in sql

Comment: `REPLACE(ab.FirstName,'''', '')`

Comment: its not working

Comment: try this one REPLACE(ab.FirstName,''', '')

Comment: Which dbms are you using? MySQL or Teradata or...?

Comment: can you mention any example value with special character in `ab.FirstName`

Comment: can you show any example

Comment: ab.FirstName=ab'c   when i tried to write in quotes as ab.FirstName='ab'c'

Comment: i m using sql server i want to remove '  from ab'c , so i want only abc

Comment: u need abc after data is fetched using query or while inserting into db

Comment: Actually i m comparing the the two values in table to fetch the record as    REPLACE(name,''', '')=REPLACE('AB O'Donnell',''', '')

Comment: so on caparison time i  want character free string as AB ODonnel

Answer (score 2):

You need to double up your single quotes like below

```
REPLACE(ab.FirstName, '''', '')
```

or

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(50) = 'ab''c'
SELECT REPLACE(@name,'''', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching records from existing table:

```
select REPLACE(ab.FirstName,'''', '')
```

If you are comparing values:

```
select REPLACE(name,'''', '')
from Table1
where name ='AB O''Donnell'
```

Comment: this is not correct name  as mentioned =AB O''Donnell

Comment: its written '' but Sql treats as ' single quote

Comment: correct name is=AB O'Donnell just one single ' character is there that creating problem

Comment: list? so you need `where` clause here. Hope its helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(100) = 'ab''c' SELECT REPLACE(@Str,'''', '')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT REPLACE(ab.FirstName,'''', '') as FirstName
```

For more details [like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please check my solution .

```
 DECLARE @stringdata nvarchar(500)='ronak'''
 select @stringdata
 select REPLACE(@stringdata,'''', '')
```

Original string is "ronak'patel" .

String after removing single quotation is "ronakpatel".

Thanks .